# database design - best practice- one table for web form drop down options or separate table for each drop down options

Tags: sql-server, database

I'm looking at the best practice approach here.  I have a web page that has several drop down options.  The drop downs are not related, they are for misc. values (location, building codes, etc).  The database right now has a table for each set of options (e.g. table for building codes, table for locations, etc).  I'm wondering if I could just combine them all into on table (called listOptions) and then just query that one table.

```
Location Table
LocationID (int)
LocatValue (nvarchar(25))
LocatDescription (nvarchar(25))

BuildingCode Table
BCID (int)
BCValue (nvarchar(25))
BCDescription (nvarchar(25))
```

Instead of the above, is there any reason why I can't do this?

```
ListOptions Table
ID (int)
listValue (nvarchar(25))
listDescription (nvarchar(25))
groupID (int) //where groupid corresponds to Location, Building Code, etc
```

Now, when I query the table, I can pass to the query the groupID to pull back the other values I need.

Comment: do you mean you want to drop the location and building table in favor of a single one?

Comment: Question is backwards. Is there any reason why I should do this. Answer No...

Comment: @vulkanino - correct, drop the single tables into one table

Comment: @TonyHopkinson So you are saying keep the individual tables?

Comment: Yes. It's clearer, it's more flexible, you can localise changes better, and it will perform better. Any gain by putting them all in one table is trivial compared to coping with having to change all of them for one....

Comment: It's also easier to add data to separate tables, e.g. when you realize the application could benefit from an `NFPA` flag on the `BuildingCode` entries.

Comment: Just to let everyone know, we are going to use separate tables after all.  One of the client groups wants to be able to sort the entries by something other than alphanumeric - why?  NO FREAKING IDEA!  Anyway, thanks for saving me future headache.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Putting in one table is an antipattern. These are differnt lookups and you cannot enforce referential integrity in the datbase (which is the ciorrect place to enforce it as applications are often not the only way data gets changed) unless they are in separate tables. Data integrity is FAR more important than saving a few minutes of development time if you need an additonal lookup.

Comment: You hit the nail on the head - I was trying to save some time but I'm quickly seeing that using one table has inherent limitations to future expansion/needs that are not known yet.

Comment: I had to look up `antipattern` and found this:
`Some repeated pattern of action, process or structure that initially appears to be beneficial, but ultimately produces more bad consequences than beneficial results, and a refactored solution exists that is clearly documented, proven in actual practice and repeatable.`

Comment: To anyone else who comes across this question, I marked this as the correct answer primarily due to the antipattern comment made by HLGEM.  Initially, the single table approach looks good but while it might save some development time now, the time needed for future enhancements would be significantly greater than spending the extra time now.  `Antipattern` what a great word.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-pattern

Answer (score 2):

You could do this.
I believe that is your master data and it would not be having any huge amounts of rows that it might create and performance problems.
Secondly, why would you want to do it once your app is up and running. It should have thought about earlier. The tables might be used in a lot of places and it's might be a lot of coding and most importantly testing.
Can you throw further light into your requirements.

Comment: Brand new spanking application, still laying out the ground work and requirements are still be debated.  I only saw a glimpse and it got me to thinking about the database design.  Separate tables would allow for future enhancements though.  This is more of a why couldn't you but I'm starting to see why separate tables would be better.

Comment: If it's in design stage, You should prefer keeping it as a single table as all of them meet the same purpose. Make sure that these tables does not depend on any other application. This will help in keeping your table's count low and your code will be maintainable. You should even consider having a word with the person who designed the table. May be he might have a reason for breaking the tables into individual tables.

Comment: No he shouldn't. Reducing table count is an irrelevancy. And they do not all meet the same purpose, they all have a common behvaviour at a high level of abstraction

Answer (score 1):

If you plan to use the values later in some referencing FKeys - better use separate tables.

But why do you need "all in one" table? Which problem it solves?

Comment: In coldfusion, I can can pass a custom tag a group id and then have the stored procedure spit out the select statement which results in cleaner code.  It doesn't really solve a problem per se, I was just curious if one was better.

Answer (score 1):

You can keep them in separate tables and have your stored procedure return one set of data with a "datatype" key that signifies which set of values go with what option.

However, I would urge you to consider a much different approach. This suggestion is based on years of building data driven websites. If these drop-down options don't change very often then why not build server-side include files instead of querying the database. We did this with most of our websites. Think about it, each time the page is presented you query the database for the same list of values... that data hardly ever changes.

In cases when that data did have the tendency to change, we simply added a routine to the back end admin that rebuilt the server-side include file whenever an add, change or delete was done to one of the lookup values. This reduced database I/O's and spead up the load time of all our websites.

We had approximately 600 websites on the same server all using the same instance of SQL Server (separate databases) our total server database I/O's were drastically reduced.

**Edit:**

We simply built SSI that looked like this...

<option value="1'>Blue</option>
<option value="2'>Red</option>
<option value="3'>Green</option>

Comment: It makes a lot of sense and if I understand correctly, the reduced db calls would increase performance.  I'd like to read up more on this suggestion - can you provide a link or a reference or google search terms I could use?  "SSI" is too broad.

Comment: what programming platform are you using? I was strictly a Microsoft shop using ASP and Sql Server.

Comment: Coldfusion 8.  I don't have a lot of experience with ssi but I believe they are similar to Colfusion's cfinclude tag.

Comment: I'm not a coldfusion programmer. We simply created a plain text file that looked just like the option code for a select statement. See my edit above. You should probably ask the coldfusion bubbas on SO how to create a text file.

Comment: Based on your edit, I understand exactly what you are suggesting.  Thanks.

Comment: I had to use &lt; to make the edit more readable. Sorry! It's correct now.

Answer (score 0):

With single table it would be easy to add new groups in favour of creating new tables, but for best practices concerns you should also have a group table so you can name those groups in the db for future maintenance

Comment: You should also consider the possibility of existing sub-groups, with that in mind i think the best way to go is multiple tables since some may have references to other groups, for example country - city

Answer (score 0):

The best practice depends on your requirements.
Do the values of location and building vary frequently? Where do the values come from? Are they imported from external data? Do other tables refer the unique table (so that I need a two-field key to preper join the tables)?
For example, I use unique table with hetorogeneus data for constants or configuration values.
But if the data vary often or are imported from external source, I prefer use separate tables.

Comment: This isn't set in stone yet but right now, the thought is there will be an admin section and within the admin section, there will be sections corresponding to the drop down options (Location Section, Building Code Section, etc) where the users can add values through a form.  They would enter the value option, the description and then update the master listOption table with the new values.